Wildfly SSL/TLS connection failed, previously working
I have an application on Wildfly 16 that was shut down 2 years ago, but was working fine at the time. I recently restarted it, but am now getting an "SSL/TLS connection failed" error, and am not sure why.
We have other applications on the same Windows server running fine on other Wildfly 16 instances. They all point to the same shared keystore.jks (updated 10 months ago). There are no errors in any log file, and in fact the server.log seems to indicate it's listening fine:
[org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 0.0.0.0:19043

CURL to a 'working' port looks like this: (In example, 'myfake.domain' and ip '155.5.555.555' are not the real values.)
>curl -v https://myfake.domain.com:18743
*   Trying 155.5.555.555:18743...
* Connected to myfake.domain.com (155.5.555.555) port 18743
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: myfake.domain.com:18743
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*

CURL to the 'failing' port:
>curl -v https://myfake.domain.com:19043
*   Trying 155.5.555.555:19043...
* Connected to myfake.domain.com (155.5.555.555) port 19043
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
* Closing connection
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with myfake.domain.com port 19043
curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed

Here's one more CURL to the 'failing' port provided by another user, that maybe gives a bit more info:
curl https://myfake.domain.com:19043 -v         
* Rebuilt URL to: https://myfake.domain.com:19043/
*   Trying 155.5.555.555...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to myfake.domain.com (155.5.555.555) port 19043 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to myfake.domain.com:19043
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to myfake.domain.com:19043

I've done a complete comparison of the full Wildfly directories between the 'working' and 'failing' apps, and have not found any key configuration differences between the two. The 'working' applications have had internal jar file changes over the past couple years, including some undertow jars. But I'm not certain if that would contribute to a previously working and untouched application now failing.
What else should I be checking? In the past 2 years, what else could have changed? Something on the Windows server itself?
UPDATE: I installed OpenSSL. This is the call from my remote PC to the network server:port.
>openssl s_client -connect myfake.domain.com:19043
Connecting to 155.5.555.555
CONNECTED(00000004)
100000000A000000:error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:689:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 340 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---


Probably not programming or development, but: if you have or can get OpenSSL, try openssl s_client -connect $host:$port for more specific info (plus quite a bit of clutter). (In the unlikely event you have OpenSSL below 1.1.1 (2018) add -servername $host.) Is the server running directly on Windows, or in WSL, docker, virtualbox, vmware, or any other virtualization method? Does netstat -ano show the correct pid (per TaskManager or tasklist) listening on that port, or if you have/get 'sysinternals' ProcessExplorer or TCPView does it show the correct process listening?

Is your certificate expired?

@JamesR.Perkins - no it is not expired, it is a shared certificate on the Windows server, with several Wildfly instances all running applications pointing to the same cert. The rest are working fine with the cert; thanks for the suggestion.

@dave_thompson_085 - I don't have openssl as of now; will try to get.
I checked the PID/port via netstat, and it's not the exact process that has the port, but it is in the process tree. This has behaved the same for all our WF applications, so I'm pretty sure it's correct.
Our apps are kicked off via Windows Service executing "...\bin\service\amd64\wildfly-service.exe .." That PID doesn't hold the port, but tracing it with wmic led to the correct parent/child PID.

@snowmanjack If you are on Windows and have Git package installed the you have openssl.exe as it is part of the Git installation. In default installation it can be found here: C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe

Thanks @Robert for the info. I installed OpenSSL, and added the output to my original post.

@dave_thompson_085 my OpenSSL output has been added to my post, if it offers anything useful for you

The output shows that on that port no TLS enabled server is running. What version of Wildly and which JRE do you use? May be the version is so old that is still expects the SSL3 handshake. This is the only guess J have at the moment. If you are really interested what is going on start the server with Java TLS debugging enabled and look at the traffic using Wireshark. May be the server response sheds some light on the problem.
